# Prove f is subharmonic fuction on $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u:C\to R$ be a continuous subharmonic function and $a>0$ be constant
proof that $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(z+ae^{i\theta})d\theta$ is also a subharmonic fuction on $C$

Answer (score 1):

1. Write down the sub-mean-value inequality for $f$. This will put one integral inside of the other, like 
   $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} u(z+re^{i\phi} +ae^{i\theta}) \,d\theta \,d\phi \tag{1}$$
2. Whenever you see a double integral, you should ask yourself: what will happen if we exchange the order of integration? Fubini allows you to, because the integrand is continuous.
3. One you realize that   $ \int_0^{2\pi} u(z+re^{i\phi} +ae^{i\theta})  \,d\phi \ge u(z  +ae^{i\theta})$  by subharmonicity of $u$, the sub-mean-value property for $f$ follows.
4. To finish the proof, demonstrate that $f$ is also continuous, by using the uniform continuity of $u$ on bounded sets.

$-\infty$. Read [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75064)